# First order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problem determining the type of this first order differential equation can someone help me how to start solving it?
The equation is:
$$2x^2y\ln(y)y'=y+xy'.$$
Thank you!

Comment: Yes but if I divide just by $y$ I will have : $2x^2log(y)y'=1+y'/y$ and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You are right ... I missed one $y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(2x^2y\ln(y)-x)\frac{dy}{dx}=y$$
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=2\ln(y)x^2-\frac{1}{y}x$$
That is a Berboulli ODE considering the function $x(y)$

Let $x(y)=\frac{1}{F(y)} \quad\to\quad \frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{F'}{F^2} $
$$-\frac{F'}{F^2} =2\ln(y)\frac{1}{F^2} -\frac{1}{yF}\quad\to\quad \frac{F}{y}-F'=2\ln(y)$$
Linear ODE : 
$$F(y)=-y\ln^2(y)+c\:y$$
$$x(y)=\frac{1}{-y\ln^2(y)+c\:y}$$
Solution on implicit form :
$$xy\big(c-\ln^2(y)\big)=1$$